# Почему не работает box-sizing:border-box?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Поясните пожалуйста почему при таком коде не работает border-box, т.е ширина и высота блока всеравно изменяются при увеличении padding.

```css
.test{
  padding:201px;
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  123213213
  </div>
```

Comment: Почему не работает? Работает :)

Comment: @meine но ведь ширина и высота блока изменилась, этого же не должно было произойти при border-box

Comment: У вас паддинги суммарно больше чем ширина/высота. Противоречие разрешается просто — ширина/высота игнорируется

Comment: @ДмитрийГаврилов, смотрите, у Вас ширина `300px`, а вы задали `padding` со всех сторон в `201px`, т.е. 201+201 = 402 => У Вас сумарная ширина `padding`'ов больше, чем заданная ширина. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.